# As the seekbar is progressed, I need to change the color of progress but it should be in a gradient format

Tags: android, android-seekbar

[image]

As shown in the figure, I need something like this but im getting single color when i slide as the progress changes. Below is the code to change the color in Onprogresschange()

```
    if(progress<41){
        seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.green_400), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.green_400), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }else if(progress>40 && progress<81) {
        seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.yellow_500), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.yellow_500), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    }else {
        seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.orange_700), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.orange_700), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
```

What im getting is of this

[image: form]

Can any one help in to get the gradient color as we change the progress, Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4pT6L2R6

Comment: it did not help, im still getting single color with rectangular background

Comment: no, you will get the gradient, just store it in `res/drawable/progress.xml` and use `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"` inside your `<SeekBar>` tag

Comment: <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
       android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        /> this is my seekbar in layout file im getting single color and rectangular view on progress

Comment: I got it, Thanks, okay How to reduce the size of rectagle of the required UI,

Comment: well, this is your homework

Comment: Thanks You that code works